# Adding an empty const constructor to a Flutter widget

Tags: flutter, dart

Consider this widget:

```dart
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyWidget();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => const Text("Hello");
}
```

Is `const MyWidget();` necessary if I want all instances of `MyWidget` to be created at compile time, or can I just remove this line?

---

In other words: I know that having a const constructor allows the instances of a class to be "canonicalized", i.e. created at compile time once per combination of constructor arguments (so just once, in this case), and I am wondering whether Dart and/or Flutter are "smart" enough to provide a default const constructor for such simple classes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No because it can have unintended consequences. `const` must be specified explicitly. It could be done easily, but it is not due to unexpected behavior.

`const` just means that only one instance of a particular object will be created if there would otherwise be multiple identical instances. This means comparison of `const` objects with identical properties would be equal, but the same could not necessarily be said about `new` objects. This doesn't really apply to flutter widgets, but it's why `const` must be explicitly specified.

Comment: Since the question asks "Is `const MyWidget();` necessary ... or can I just remove this line?", it's unclear what "No because it can have unintended consequences..." is referring to.  I presume you mean "You cannot remove the empty `const` constructor..."

Comment: @jamesdlin Yeah thanks for the clarification. I was more looking at the "...Dart and/or Flutter are "smart" enough to..." part when I was answering.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to declare such simple default constructor. There's a default one but it's not `const` constructor. So if you want your widget to be constant you need to create a constructor like this, but only in this case